# How to count the number of archives there are

Tags: archives, count

Is there a way to count the number of monthly archives? For example, my site has the 3 monthly archives (jan 2016, feb 2016). So the number should be 2. How I can display the count.

PS: I want to display the count beside the Archives Label in my sitemap

I tried with the following with no success.

```
<?php 
$args = array(
  'parent' => 0,
  'hide_empty' => 0
  );
$arch_count  = wp_get_archives($args); 

echo count ($arch_count);
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Notes:**

- Currently you're *echo*-ing the output of `wp_get_archives()`. In order to *return* it, we must set the `echo` input parameter to `false`.
- You're assuming the output of `wp_get_archives()` is an *array*, but it's a *string*.

**Workaround:**

Here's one way, by counting the `<li>` instances, with the `html` format:

```
$args = [
  'parent'     => 0,
  'hide_empty' => 0,
  'echo'       => 0,
  'format'     => 'html',
];

$archive_count = substr_count( wp_get_archives( $args ), '<li>' );
```

Here we assume the `<li>` isn't modified by the `get_archives_link` filter.

**Update:**

Here's another approach by using the `get_archives_link` filter to tick the counter. This should be able to handle the counting for all types of `wp_get_archvies()`.

Let's create a general wrapper of `wp_get_archives()`, to get both the output and the count as well.

First we create an instance of `MyArchive`:

```
$myarchive = new MyArchive;
```

Then we generate it with the relevant arguments:

```
$myarchive->generate( $args );
```

To get the count we use:

```
$archive_count = $myarchive->getCount();
```

and we get the output with:

```
$archive_html = $myarchive->getHtml();
```

Here we define the `MyArchive` wrapper as (demo):

```
class MyArchive
{
    private $count;
    private $html;

    public function getCount()
    {
        return (int) $this->count;
    }
    public function getHtml()
    {
        return $this->html;
    }
    public function generate( array $args )
    {
        $this->count = 0;

        // Make sure we return the output
        $args['echo'] = false;  

        // Do the counting via filter
        add_filter( 'get_archives_link',    [ $this, 'getArchivesLink' ] );

        // Generate the archives and store it
        $this->html = wp_get_archives( $args );

        // Remove filter
        remove_filter( 'get_archives_link', [ $this, 'getArchivesLink' ] );

        return $this;
    }       
    public function getArchivesLink( $link )
    {
        $this->count++;
        return $link;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool!.. This will do. Thanks a lot for this. I highly appreciate this.

Comment: I updated the answer with a (hopefully) more general method @Ayanize